# Get/give/under/make an Impression

Tags: grammar, expressions, prepositions, sentence

What's the difference between:
1) Get an/the impression
2) Give an/the impression
3) Make an/the important
4) Under an/the impression.

Example sentences would be really appreciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1 He got the impression that she didn't like him when she slapped him. = He thought that

2. She gave the impression of being very angry. = She appeared to be.
3. He made an impression by wearing a red suit to an interview. = What he did was noticed by others.
4. He was under the impression that 50 was the speed limit. = He thought that.

1 and 4 differ slightly as 1 he thinks when the slap occurs, whereas 4 suggests it is an ongoing thought.